# Vertical scrollbar scrollup-scrolldown images look jagged on Qtopia machine

Tags: qt

I am trying to use a vertical scrollbar in my Qt project.
The issue is when use the Cleanlooks widget style for the vertical scrollbar,it looks ok on the Linux Ubuntu machine,where Qt-4.3.3 is running.
But,when i run the same project on a Qtopia-4.3.3 Linux(ARM) machine,the scrolldown and scrollup images look totally jagged. They,look very bad. I tried using stylesheets,but without luck. Any suggestions regarding using stylesheets are most welcome.
Is there any way,to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my relatively small experience with styles on embedded platforms, some of the styles are designed so they use an image for certain things, and scale it as necessary.  This produces very jagged graphics if the source is small and the target it large.  One possibility is to inherit your own `QStyle` from the Cleanlooks style, and override the drawing of the arrow images with your own drawing code.  It shouldn't be too hard to draw a proper arrow in code, rather than using an image.